# How to retrieve values from json response of a CURL request when using ansible command module?

Tags: json, shell, curl, ansible, extract

I am using Ansible to test some APIs. Instead of using get_url or uri module of ansible, i am using Curl requests with command/shell module.

I would need to extract a particular value from the json response of a curl api call, so that i can use that value in next curl request.

For example,

```
- name: Run a curl request to login and get jwt token
  command:  curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"user":"{{username}}","password":"{{password}}"}' https://localhost:8001/api/v1/login
  register: login_response

- name: Print the jwt response
  debug:
    var: login_response.stdout  

- name: Run a curl request to get service token
  command:  curl -k -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer {{login_response.stdout.jwt}}" https://localhost:8001/api/v1/servicetoken/issue
  register: service_token

- name: Print service token
  debug:
    var: service_token.stdout
```

The above ansible playbook will fail at third task because it cannot find a variable like:

```
login_response.stdout.jwt
```

Normally the variable in second task, ie, login_response.stdout  will print something like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "login_response.stdout": {
        "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6ImFiNmU0ZDg2LWE4YzgtNDU4OS04MmRiLWIxZTg1YzQwNDNlZiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDU2MTIxODAuNjA5MTI1NCwiaWF0IjoxNjA1NjExODgwLjYwOTEyMC42MDkxMjU0fQ.ZC4a3H3j03ZmzDkjGj11cvxSls2qXZmVOGuIvKp8LHVpYOUyEJlWJJOTArHxKhxne3DsuqWoGpslR6KxuUOBFg",
        "roles": [
            {
                "name": "Admin"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What i want is to extract that jwt token from the above response and use it in third task.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What is wrong with the `uri` module in your scenario ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I got an error like this when tried to use uri module :  `The error was: NetrcParseError: ~/.netrc file owner (Muser) does not match current user (root) (/home/Muser/.netrc, line 3)`

Comment: Why do you need to be root to request on an API ? `become: false`  on the play or on this particular task should fix that issue.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you so much for the fix.... As of now, I was testing the playbook on my local machine. That's when this error occurred. Actually these tasks are part of another playbook which was made to execute in a remote host as root user. That's why the requests came from root user by default!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

This can be achieved using **[from_json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json)** filter in order to make ansible able to access the json fields.

Now the working playbook should be like:

```
- name: Run a curl request to login and get jwt token
  command:  curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"user":"{{username}}","password":"{{password}}"}' https://localhost:8001/api/v1/login
  register: login_response

- name: Print the jwt token
  debug:
    var: (login_response.stdout|from_json).jwt   

- name: Run a curl request to get service token
  command:  curl -k -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer {{(login_response.stdout|from_json).jwt}}" https://localhost:8001/api/v1/servicetoken/issue
  register: service_token

- name: Print service token
  debug:
    var: (service_token.stdout|from_json).token
```

I refered here to get the idea: https://medium.com/@justinhennessy/parsing-json-with-ansible-bcbb8d4b6a54